# PayPal IPN INVALID result using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I have looked into many if not all questions in Stackoverflow for an answer to this, and I couldn't find it.

I am having a problem with PayPal IPN. I am testing it using sanbox and IPN Simulator. I am also using PHP and cURL to validate the response coming from PayPal. But I am getting only INVALID result of response. I can't seem to get VERIFIED.

I think the problem is that I am not sending back the EXACT URL to PayPal. You can see my code below for the IPN Listener:

```
<?php

require_once('../includes/main.php');

// Prepare the URL to send via cURL
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Initial cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Set opt
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.paypal.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

// Return result
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL connection
curl_close($ch);

// If condition
if(strpos($result, "VERIFIED") != false){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO paypal_ipn (ipn_message, verification) VALUES ('{$request}', '{$result}')");
}else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO paypal_ipn (ipn_message, verification) VALUES ('{$request}', '{$result}')");
}?>
```

Comment: I might solve the problem if I know how to compare URLs. But I don't know how to get the URL.

Comment: Have you `var_dump($result)` and see what's in it?

Comment: @frz3993 I just did that and the `var_dump` was equal to NULL. and the result is still INVALID

Comment: @frz3993 Maybe there is something wrong with the urlencoding. How can I match the response with paypal string values?

Comment: @frz3993 Check out my answer below. I have found a solution but there is another problem. If you can help me with it I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The problem INVALID was because of the TIME that was sent was is equal to GMT + 3 which made it invalid. After I changed it to GMT without + 3 it worked, returned VERIFIED.

But the question is why did it return INVALID when I used GMT+3 how can I make it work with GMT+3?

Comment: I cannot believe this worked. This has taken me 2 days of constant frustration, changing cUrl options etc and final on the simulator I just removed the "GMT+0100" and it worked. Paypal?!!

Comment: @Andy Great to hear that you have found the answer. It also took me two days at the time. You are welcome.